# How to save qml style including function in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, style, qml

I made a **style which needs function** to work. In my particular case it is calculating azimuth between nodes of rectangles to display "direction".

[image]
[image]

The problem is, **if I save the style, the function is not saved with it**. So if somebody else wants to look at it on other computer, the function is missing and style doesn't work as expected. Is there some way to include function or workaround to not need to use function to achieve saving the style including the calculation of direction?

Poor workaround like create new column which will be populated with this function is not an option here because the key is interactive response of style on change / addition of rectangle.

Comment: IMHO it's can be considered a bug... anything related with a symobol o a rendere would be saved in QML... may you file a qgis issue?

Comment: Not sure.  I didn't add support for that because of the complications it adds.

Answer (score 4):

The expression functions are all stored under `.qgis2\python\expressions` You can copy and install them onto any machine that needs them.  The other option is to add them as a Python macro for the project under `Project -> Properties -> Marcos`.  Paste the text of your expression function in the there.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, macro seems to be good option for me. I am going to test it tomorrow. You mentioned that adding function into style would add complications but also it causes complications without it :)

Comment: The life of a developer ;)

Comment: Macro doesn't work in this case, when I open the project on other computer it asks for allowing macros but because the layer style is already loaded without the function, enabling macros doesn't do anything with it.